# How to read and break down complex lambda equations in python

Tags: python, function, lambda, higher-order-functions

This question below is from a past year NUS exam paper, and im not sure how to go about solving this; how do you break down the lambda parts and figure out which bracket is for which lambda variable? I'm unable to trace the code to get 120

```
def combinator(y):
    return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y)
combinator(lambda x:x*10)(11)(12)
```

Ive tried to google but the lambda tutorials are mostly basic so im not sure how to read and break down more complex lambda codes and higher order functions

Answer (score 0):

The function is

```py
def combinator(y):
    return (lambda x: lambda y: x(y))(lambda x:y)
combinator(lambda x:x*10)(11)(12)
```

Let's try to simplify the function. First, take note that you can change the symbol for a function. For example, `lambda x: x` can be changed to `lambda z: z`.

As there are a lot of `x` and `y`, we will change the symbols to reduce the confusion.

```py
def combinator(y):
    return (lambda w: lambda z: w(z))(lambda x:y)
combinator(lambda x:x*10)(11)(12)
```

Let's try to define the function as mathematics function to make it easier to understand. Let's set
`f` represents `lambda x:x*10`, so `f(x) = x*10`
`g` represents `lambda x:y`, so `g(x) = y`
`h` represents `lambda z:w(z)`, so `h(z) = w(z) => h = w`
`k` represents `lambda w: lambda z: w(z)`, so `k(w) = h = w`

With the mathematics function defined, you can substitute them back to the function.

```bash
combinator(y)
= (lambda w: lambda z: w(z))(lambda x:y)  
= k(g)
= g
```

Therefore, we know that `combinator(y) = g`

```bash
combinator(y)(x) = g(x) = y
combinator(y)(x)(z) = y(z)
```

Therefore

```bash
combinator(lambda x:x*10)(11)(12)
= combinator(f)(11)(12)
= f(12)
= 12*10
= 120
```